# Correcting for bounds in latent variable in regression

Tags: regression, bias, latent-variable

I have a variable $y_{i,t}$ that takes values from $[0,\infty)$ for individual $i$ and for $t=1,2$. I construct a variable $\Delta y_{i} = y_{i,2} - y_{i,1}$. For most of my sample (73%), $y_{i,1} = 1$. Hence mechanically, for individuals with $y_{i,1} = 1$, their $\Delta y_{i}$ is bounded below by -1.

Suppose I'm interested in the relationship between $\Delta y_{i}$ and $x_i$. $x_i$ takes in any values from $(-\infty,\infty)$. Suppose that the true underlying relationship between $\Delta y_i$ and $x_i$ is: $\Delta y_i = -10 x_i$. However, in our sample, we observe a lot of high values of $x_i$, like $x_i = 100$. Since for many of my sample, $\Delta y_i$ is bounded below by -1, the OLS estimate will be biased.

How can I correct for this bias introduced by regressing on the latent variable that is bounded, rather than the actual unobserved variable?